# What is the Mac equivilent of ALT+PrintScreen?

Tags: keyboard, screen-capture

I've just started using Delphi to create OSX programs. I'd like to be able to take a screenshot of just the currently active window on the Mac and save it to the clipboard. On Windows you press [Alt] + [PrtScn].

What is the equivilent on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

To take a screenshot of a window press: <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. With this hover the mouse over the window You want to take a screenshot of and press Left mouse/trackpad button.